# Amazon Linux AMI doesn't have php 7.1.3 (it only installs php 7.1.28)

Tags: linux, php, amazon-web-services, lamp

I had in ec2 instance with AWS, when running following commands,

```
1  yum update -y
2  yum install -y httpd24 php71 mysql56-server php71-mysqlnd
```

will install only php 7.1.28, but i want php 7.1.3 (because my laravel 5.7 needs this php version)

How can i update?

Comment: I’d guess you need a more recent version of the base OS/image. Never used Amazon Linux myself though.

Comment: 7.1.28 is a much **newer** release than 7.1.3... https://www.php.net/releases/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the version of Amazon Linux by doing `uname -a` - What does this return? As far as I can tell there are 2 release each year in March and September (eg 2019.03 and 2019.09). This might be worth doing since there are security releases, but you should be trying to use ephermal repeatable infrastructure within AMS if you can.

You could also add a [repository yourself](https://tecadmin.net/install-php7-on-centos7/), which involves first adding the EPEL repository, then secondly the 'remi' repoistory which has php7.3 amonsgt other versions packaged into RPMs.